# Open MPI, determine rank of process to send to

Tags: openmpi, rank

I have two different executables each with a specific role. One of the two processes sends the other information by calling **MPI_isend**. But how do I know the rank of the other process?
I found out that when I run my stack as follows, that exe1, the receiving process, seems to always have rank 0, exe2 seems to always have rank 1. Therefore, if I send to rank 0 from exe2, the message is received. But am I missing anything here, it seems so complicated?

**mpirun -np 1 exe1 : -np 1 exe2**

Comment: That's incorrect, one has rank 0, the other rank 1

Comment: It just depends how you execute your program `-np 1 firstPrograme: -np 1 secondProgram` the first in the list has the npth first rank etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mapping of processes to ranks in Open MPI can be controlled with various CLI arguments to `mpiexec` with newer versions (like 1.7.x) supporting much finer control than older versions. By default ranks follow the order in which processes are placed in the slots provided. Therefore `-np 1 exe1 : -np 1 exe2` will always result in `exe1` being rank `0` and `exe2` being rank `1` in `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. If you use `-np 3 exe1 : -np 2 exe2` instead, you will get the following:

```
rank    executable
------------------
0       exe1
1       exe1
2       exe1
3       exe2
4       exe2
```

It is also possible to start `exe1` and `exe2` as separate MPI jobs and make them connect to each other over an intercommunicator but that is considered an advanced MPI topic.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be, to have the receiving process, exe1, send a message with its rank first. When the second process listens for messages from any source with the tag of that message, it will receive the rank of the first process.